# Apache Netbeans 11 sample database available?

Tags: java, netbeans, derby

In the past I used Netbeans 8 for my projects and there was a sample database included which everyone can use. Now I installed the new Netbeans version 11.2 and wanted to create a simple project with the sample database, but I cant find it. Is there no sample database anymore?

Comment: Apache Derby used to be bundled in various other software packages but that stopped quite a while ago. But you can still download Apache Derby yourself and use it from Netbeans: http://db.apache.org/derby

Comment: This [documentation on setting up a Derby database on NetBeans for a college class](https://web.csulb.edu/~mopkins/cecs323/netbeans.shtml) is thorough, and fairly up to date.

Comment: Derby was bundled with previous versions of Java, not with NetBeans to be precise. But I would recommend [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) over Derby though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample database available if you use Java DB. To use it in Netbeans 11, you have to install it from https://db.apache.org/derby, as it was already said in the comments above. 
Once you have set up JavaDB in Netbeans (right click on Java DB -> Properties) you can right click Java DB and then choose "Create Sample Database...".

Attention! With Derby >= 10.15 they started to modularize it (JPMS), and being so they split the drivers into separate JARs and NB 11 is not yet aware of it (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-3424). So you have to add derbyshared.jar and derbytools.jar to your "Java DB (Embedded)" and "Java DB (Network)" drivers, otherwise you will get errors that the driver cannot be found.